# Regex to not match tags with attributes?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, html-parsing

=========================================================================

**EDIT:**
I'm using node.js, so I don't have access to the DOM, and parsing with an HTML parser is not an option (it's not efficient enough to justify passing through such a small amount of text)

=========================================================================

First off, I know. HTML + Regex = fail. However, I just need it to remove all tags with attributes.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    exports.strip_tags = function(input, allowed) {
      // Strips HTML and PHP tags from a string
   allowed = (((allowed || "") + "")
     .toLowerCase()
     .match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || [])
     .join('');
      var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]>/gi,
      commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
      return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function($0, $1){
        return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
      });
    }
```

Any chance someone knows how to change up one of these regex's to make this remove what I need it to?

To clarify: This function should remove all tags with attributes, keep only the tags that are allowed (without attributes), and output the result.

Comment: HTML + Regex = fail. Seriously, you even admit it, why keep trying? There's better alternatives that don't invoke Ctulhu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @litso The string that we're talking about here is tiny though, a parser seems like overkill. At most we're talking about a paragraph.

Comment: @robert, that's what I was referring to :P
@techwraith, I see. Can't really help you though, but I see your point :)

Comment: Why does it matter if the HTML string is tiny or huge? Use a parser - or, if it's really that small, edit the string by hand.

Comment: @Bears Doing it by hand is not an option, and loading a parser each time I want to process something as small as a paragraph is definitely overkill. Already Fixed my problem though. If someone doesn't post an answer within a few days I'll post it up for future reference.

Comment: @Tech I hope said answer involves no Regex.

Comment: @Tech - I think you missed my point. Glad to hear you solved the problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to XHTML and then use xpath.

HTML->XHTML tools:

- http://tidy.sourceforge.net/
- http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader

As you said....  HTML + Regex = fail